# Генератор тестов

Tags: php, mysql

Привет, привет! Ребята, пытаюсь сделать генератор тестов на php, который берет случайные вопросы из БД по номеру блока и выводит к ним 4 случайных ответа, один из которых обязательно правильный.
Есть таблица вопросов со столбцами: ID, Vopros, Block и таблица ответов: ID, Otvet, ID_vopr, Znach - 0 или 1 для обозначения правильного ответа.
По уму нужно бы сделать несколько типов вопросов: с одним вариантом (radio), с несколькими вариантами (checkbox) и хотя бы с выбором из выпадающего списка.

```
//Здесь выводится случайный вопрос из таблицы Vopr
while ($num<=5) {

$query = "SELECT * FROM Vopr WHERE Block='$num'";

$q=@mysql_query ($query);

if(!$q) break;

while ($row=@mysql_fetch_array($q))

{$quest[]=$row;}

$current=$quest[rand(0,count($quest)-1)];

echo "<hr>";

echo $current['Vopros'];

echo "</hr>";

echo "<input type='hidden' name='q[$num]'

value='".$current['ID']."'>";
//а вот тут начинаются проблемы
/*если выводить одним запросом 4 ответа случайных - то в них может не войти правильный ответ, и чем больше вариантов ответа - там больше шанс промаха*/
/*в качестве костыля я сделал вывод отдельно правильного и неправильного варианта, пока не придумал нормального решения*/
$query2= "SELECT * FROM Otv_easy WHERE ID_vopr='".$current['ID']."' AND Znach='1'";
$query3= "SELECT * FROM Otv_easy WHERE ID_vopr='".$current['ID']."' AND Znach='0' ORDER BY RAND() limit 3";

$a=@mysql_query ($query2);
$b=@mysql_query ($query3);


while ($arow=@mysql_fetch_array($a))

{ echo "<p><input type='checkbox' name='a[$num]' value='".$arow ['ID']."'> ".$arow ['Otvet']." </p>";

}
while ($arow=@mysql_fetch_array($b))

{ echo "<p><input type='checkbox' name='a[$num]' value='".$arow ['ID']."'> ".$arow ['Otvet']." </p>";
}

unset($quest);

$num++; // переходим к следующему вопросу

}
echo "<INPUT TYPE=submit VALUE='Отправить'>";
```

Вот тут возникает первый вопрос: Как избавиться от костыля и заносить результаты запросов $query2 и $query3 в массив, после этого сортировать его и выводить в качестве ответов?

С проверкой правильных ответов для radio-кнопок я вроде бы разобрался.
Вот форма, которая проверяет правильные ответы и считает баллы:

```
for ($i=1; $i<=count($q); $i++)

{$query="SELECT * FROM otv WHERE ID_vopr='".$q[$i]."' AND Znach='1'"; 

$p=@mysql_query($query);

$row=@mysql_fetch_array($p);

$answer = $row['ID'];
if($a[$i]==$answer) 
$ball++;

unset($query,$p,$row);

}
```

Но с её помощью не получается правильно считать баллы за checkbox, потому что идет проверка до первого элемента и если в checkbox'е стоит два ответа - ответ считается не верным, если отмечен только второй правильный ответ - ответ считается не верным.

Перепробовал уже кучу вариантов и сам же в них успел запутаться. Третий день бьюсь над этим.
Как сделать подсчет баллов за правильные ответы для checkbox?

Хочу сразу оговориться, что задание выполняю в силу необходимости и до этого момента сталкиваться с php не приходилось, поэтому не обладаю необходимым багажом знаний. И рад бы изучить огромный толмут по языку, но займет это не день, не два и не неделю :(
Выручайте, братцы!

Comment: Зачем вы тяните в php кучу записей и берете 1 случайную ? `select * from Vopr order by rand() limit 1` даст вам из базы ровно 1 случайную запись. Не надо делать `select *`. никогда. явно выбирайте только требуемые колонки. В php используйте функции PDO, а не mysql_*. Никогда не пишите `value='".$arow ['ID']."` используйте bind_param (PDO). PDO кстати может вернуть сразу массив из запроса. Запросы 2 и 3 стоит объединить в один

Comment: @Mike Если объединять запросы 1 и 2, то в итоге вытягиваются 4 случайных ответа и в них может не войти правильный. И чем больше вариантов ответов на один вопрос - тем больше шанс, что среди них не будет правильного. Мне же нужно вытянуть 4 ответа, среди которых 1 правильный.

Comment: `order by if(Znach=1,-1,rand()) limit 4` гарантированно выдаст верный ответ в результате. правда он будет всегда первым. Но вы и так сейчас верный ответ всегда выводите первым. что бы этого избежать надо запрос завернуть еще в один select и дать еще раз order by rand()

Comment: @Mike Да, действительно такое решение для вывода правильного ответа работает и смотрится весьма прилично. Но я не могу понять, как завернуть запрос в ещё один select. Везде в описании Select тянет данные из БД. Не записывать же результат первого запроса в БД, что бы потом оттуда вытянуть через второй select?

Comment: @Mike Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.

Comment: `select * from (select * from Otv_easy ... order by if(Znach=1,-1,rand()) limit 4) A order by rand()` Главное букву A (или любое название) не забудьте поставить после скобки в которой внутренний селект завернут, это имя подзапроса, mysql без него ошибки выдает.

Comment: @Mike Большое спасибо! :) Пол дела сделано! Вопросы вытягиваются из БД в случайном порядке, к ним корректно подтягиваются ответы и даже правильно считаются баллы за ответ. Но, к сожалению, пока что только для вопросов с одним правильным ответом (<input type='Radio'>). Я так понимаю, что для проверки checkbox нужно как-то реализовать цикл, который будет проверять все 4 ответа?

Comment: А вы после получения ответа из браузера var_dump($_POST) (или GET) напечатайте, посмотрите как ответы возвращаются. Что то мне подсказывает что там будет массив с отмеченными пунктами

Comment: Вывсе галочки что ли поставили, что то в 'a' у вас много значений. В общем видимо foreach пробежаться по массиву $_POST['a']. Там видимо список id ответов

Comment: @Mike Вообще получается странная ситуация. Один вопрос считается правильным при двух ответах со Znach=1, а второй вопрос считается правильным если выбрать только первый из двух правильный. Если выбрать только второй из двух или оба - то результат так же 0.

Comment: В том коде проверок что у вас, вы из базы выбираете только одну запись с Znach=1. Если их несколько вам там нужен цикл чтения ну или получения готового массива

Comment: @Mike Не могу догнать как сделать цикл чтения. Или результат не меняется или зацикливается и сайт зависает. Вроде и спрашивать стыдно, потому что должно быть не сложно, но разобраться и доделать не могу.

Comment: @Mike Приветствую! Убрал все костыли, которые нашел, осталась одна проблема. Checkbox передает только одно последнее значение.  `echo "<p><input type='checkbox' name='a[$num]',  value='".$arow ['ID']."'> ".$arow ['Otvet']." </p>";` эта строчка выводит ответы и потом передает их дальше, и получается, что a[$num] затирается последним значением. Как можно разделить один checkbox на 4 переменных, что бы потом выполнять подсчет баллов?

Comment: @LexxoR34 Ничего не понял. куда дальше и что она передает. кроме вывода от нее ничего не требуется. А браузер возвращает все, что ввели у чего разные имена, так что с разными $num ничего затирать не будет. Правда у вас он почему то постоянный. так допишите к нему что нибудь что бы обеспечить уникальность